# A good Eclipse for PHP in Ubuntu 11.10 tutorial

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

Well I´m just moving in to Linux, so I´m using Ubuntu, I installed Ubuntu 11.10, so I was wondering if anyone can give me a hand on how to install succesfuly Eclipse to develope in PHP, I used to use Eclipse Helios (Windows 7), but helios is not inside Ubuntu´s repository, so I guess I´ll have to try it manually. Still prefer to download it from repository not so good with command lines.

Anyone knows a good tutorial?, I´m a newbie in linux so please be very descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an older thread so don't know whether this is still helpfull. Why do you need helios? If you go to the help -> install new software in eclipse then select indigo update site end search for pdt (php development kit). Then install and restart afterwards and their you have a php-perspective with pretty much everything you will need.

Comment: Thanks, what I did is installed Indigo and then put the Helios package to use php as in Helios, runs very very well, same thing I did with subversion and it's woderful.Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ubuntu. Their forums are very good as well. To get started you should always use Synaptic or Aptitude APT to get and install packages (software) in Ubuntu. That way the system knows and tracks release and upgrade info.

So open Synaptic and search for Eclipse.. Check it "Marked for Installation" and apply it. It will then install the Eclipse distro for your release. From there it is the same as windows in terms of configuring and installing plug-ins, etc.. It will be installed in "Applications -> Programming"

There is also a Software Center in Ubuntu that may also have Eclipse and other dev tools. You may also need to install "server headers" in you Ubuntu environment to get the dev-tools. I am  not sure in 11.10

Comment: nice, I did that, but it doesný apply correctly for some reason using aptitude. Using software center it only installas indigo and I need helios as for PHP developers. Man I´m so stuck, thanks anyway